# WPF Translate and Scale at same time, Scale appears to use original position

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am attempting to slide an image to the right, while flipping it over (it is a card).  I can flip it in place, or I can move it to the destination, individually without issue.

Combining the two transforms is not working as I intended.  The image will Translate over, and then when it starts the ScaleX, it moves it back past the original spot.  So if I translated it +300, a scale of -1 appears to translate it to -300.  It has the flipping effect, but I want it to Flip in place.

Ideally it would flip while moving, but one step at a time.

I believe the issue is, Scale applies to the enlarged space of the Translate.  Even though I am moving it, it uses the new position relative to the original (or the stack panel has widened) and so it flips to the other side of the original position.  I need it to flip on it's Center, using only the width of the card itself.  So from X=0, move to X=300, then ScaleX as if X=300 was the origin for ScaleX (for it to trade the X=300 new position as if it were X=0, causing a flip in place).  This is what I am at a loss for and cannot find this online, I understand what is happening but not the correct method to achieve my goal.  Lots of single transformation information, but not when they are combined like this.

```
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <TransformGroup.Children>
                            <TransformCollection>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="TransformTranslate" X="10" Y="10" />
                                <ScaleTransform x:Name="TransformScale" ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"/>
                            </TransformCollection>
                        </TransformGroup.Children>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                <StackPanel.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <!-- Slide the card -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransformTranslate"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                         From="10" To="300" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransformTranslate"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TranslateTransform.X)"
                                                         From="300" To="10" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:4" />

                                <!-- Flip(Scale) the image -->
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransformScale"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                            From="1" To="-1" Duration="0:0:2" BeginTime="0:0:1" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TransformScale"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                            From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0" BeginTime="0:0:3" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </StackPanel.Triggers>

                <Border Background="{Binding CardDisplay.Background}"  Width="200" Height="278" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Image Source="/Images/CardBack.png" Width="200" Height="300" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: You should try to animate sequential using key frames. Scale first and then translate.

Comment: Change the order of the transforms. First scale, then translate. Don't listen to people saying animations suck. They probably just don't understand how they work.

Comment: The best answer I could come up with was as you both said, Scale first, then translate.  Or, separate Scale and Translate onto different items that appear and disappear as required, giving the illusion of a single animated item if the timing is set up correctly.